# What would be a good test Orchestration tool for Python unit tests?

Tags: python, automated-testing

What comes to mind is `Make`, or `build.xml`, but I have not found a comprehensive `Orchestration` tool for *python* testing yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By `build.xml` do you mean Ant?

Comment: yes, by build.xml, i mean all ant and ant like (ruby, etc) build systems

Answer (score 2):

try using [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/), it should run all unit tests of a project with one single command

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use either make, or setup.py - or the two in combination. make to provide a consistent interface that other tools understand, and do adhoc stuff. setup.py to do building of extension modules, generation of releases and so forth.

http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index